# How to configure an Android smartphone not to lock itself too quickly?

Tags: security, battery-life

I am alone at home, working on my laptop. The phone lies nearby on the table. Occasionally somebody texts me, I take and unlock it to see what's up. Then, after I put it away, in 15 seconds it turns the screen off (that's ok). A second after somebody texts me again and I am to unlock it (connect the dots) again... and again and again and again...

Is there a way to configure screen standby and lock timeouts separately? Can I prevent the phone from locking itself too quickly without postponing the screen standby and without disabling the screen lock completely?

Comment: Could you use Smart Lock? That way it would stay unlocked when at home but you'd still have the lock screen when not at home. You don't say what phone you have so it's hard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Some devices offer this setting. Have you checked your settings under `Settings > Security` or `Settings > Lockscreen` (may depend on the device). There should be a setting which let's you define after how much time the phone should be locked and if pressing the power-button instantly locks the device :) Pretty much [like this](http://images.techhive.com/images/article/2015/04/killer-android-features-11timeout-100580339-large.idge.png) or [like this](http://www.androidauthority.com/screen-timeout-572050/)